# https and DNS over https... VPN still needed?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, https

Does using DNS over https + https web pages give equivalent privacy to using a VPN?

The DNS service also needs to be trusted (e.g. that they only keep certain logs, for so many days not keeping identifiable info etc...). Is it more or less easy to verify a DNS providers claims, as compared to a VPN provider? And... is it more critical if one or the other turns out not to be trustworthy?

Can a ISP log which sites are visited if you are using DNS over https?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Super User! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour). At present, your question seems to be asking multiple questions, which isn't really suitable for a Q&A site like this one. Can I suggest you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1459747/edit) your post to get it to a specific question you want answered? Background info/context is fine (preferable actually), but when it's cased with other questions it reduces your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not equivalent, and yes, an ISP can see what sites you visit.

The privacy is not equivalent, but it is complimentary. Combined, they give good privacy.

Your ISP can see the IP addresses you send data to. With a VPN (or, for that matter, [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/)), they only see you send data to the VPN provider (or the Tor network).

If you use unencrypted DNS lookups, the IP addresses of the sites you visit can be logged, even if you use a VPN. Someone could be snooping in on your traffic. I suspect it's not always legal for an ISP to do so, but they could. They would then see what IP addresses you're looking up, even if they can't see that you're actually visiting those addresses.

If you have encrypted traffic and DNS lookups, and use a VPN, your ISP (or someone else with access to the traffic from your machines) cannot easily see what you're doing.